# Recovery data in client side using selectors -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, frontend

Good night,

I'm having trouble retrieving the tag value;

```
let salarys = document.querySelectorAll('#salarys');

//return => NodeList(9) [p#salarys, p#salarys, p#salarys, p#salarys, p#salarys, p#salarys, 
p#salarys, p#salarys, p#salarys].
```

when I access the vector at position 0

it return

```
<p id="salarys" value="R$ 6.000,00"></p>
```

My problem is I can't get the value

when i use script

```
 console.log(salarys[0].value);
 // return undefined
```

I can't understand why it happens...

i need recovery all salarys value.

Thanks =)

Comment: `.value` is to get the value inside of the tags, since your value is inside of an attribute you should use `getAttribute('value')`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
let salarys = document.querySelectorAll('#salarys');
console.log(salarys[0].getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p` element does not have a `value` attribute. **If you want to make a custom attribute**, you can prefix the attribute name with `data-`, like:

```js
const
  salarys = document.getElementById("salarys"),
  val = salarys.dataset.value; // Access data-properties via `dataset`
console.log(val);
```

```html
<p id="salarys" data-value="R$ 6.000,00"></p>
```

Alternatively, if you want to use **the text that appears to the user within the paragraph element, this is available in the `textContent`** property:

```js
const
  salarys = document.getElementById("salarys"),
  text = salarys.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<p id="salarys">R$ 6.000,00</p>
```